# VB6: How to create a DLL and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a VB6 Class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257883/using-a-vb6-class-in-c)

I have a serialization egnine written in VB6, which makes binary serialization in some mysterious way I didn't get to figure out. I also have a C# program that needs to make serialization the same way the VB6 code does.

So I wanted to make the VB6 serialization code in DLL and use it in the C# program so that the binary serialization would fit. How can I do that?

Comment: as simple as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257883/using-a-vb6-class-in-c

Comment: Just compile the vb code into a dll using visual studio 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VB6 classes are COM objects, and C# can use them via COM-interop.

Set your VB project to build an in-process COM server, then add it to the C# project as a COM reference.

Comment: What did you mean by saying "an in-process COM server"? what does it have to do with server and how do I do that? Sorry but I didn't understand so well, and I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @Giora: It's a setting in your VB6 project properties.