# VB6 application in background or invisible to end user

Tags: vb6, backgroundworker

I want to run my VB6 application in background or invisible to user.

How can we achieve it?

Comment: I thought trolling was discouraged here.

Comment: @David @Bob I don't think David is *quite* trolling, although maybe getting uncomfortably close to it :) However I think his comments are possibly in the wrong question. These issues are addressed in questions like [will VB6 live forever like Cobol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400479/vb6-lives-forever-like-cobol) and [what are the risks around continuing to rely on VB6 applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319561/risks-around-relying-on-vb6-applications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write it as a formless application, or else write it to start in `Sub Main()` and then `Load` but don't `Show` your main Form.

Module1.bas

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Main()
    Load Form1
End Sub
```

Form1.frm

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer1.Interval = 5000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If MsgBox("Hello", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Unload Me
End Sub
```